# Is it possible to publish different tests results in Azure Devops?

Tags: testing, azure-devops

I would like to publish different tests results. I have two suites. The last one overrides the results of the first one. Is it possible to get both on the same page below “tests and coverage”?

Comment: What is the test task in your pipeline to execute the tests, and what is the test result format?If you use dotnet test task or Vstest task. Multiple test results can be shown in the test tab together. They will be automatically merged.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't want them to be merged. I want two results, each one for each tests suites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer this question, no there's not. You can merge the results of two different suite tests. You can also save the results elsewhere. But it's not possible to display two different results for two different suite tests inside the Azure DevOps Gui.